# Subversion Android studio on mac os

Tags: android, svn

I must use subversion on Android studio for a project, and I've a mac.
But subversion on Android Studio doesn't work for me. I'm using RapidSVN
[image]

and when I want to import to Subversion there is an error

[image]

if somebody can help me and tell me what exactly he does to use it, because I've use SmartSVN,svnX,syncroSVN and it is the same error.

Comment: A Mac cannot run .exe files because they're only for windows.

Answer (score 1):

First of all use a Mac OS X version of your SVN client.

Install and try it from command line, according to your SVN client, then you can check if it works under Android Studio